# How to get value from input?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

I make simple task  for getting job. Working with react and redux. When i get value from input and send them to reducer they are lost in the way. Wait, not so easy. 1st item getting by reducer gets prop name, age, type, index and return new state. Nice. But other items lost prop name and age in the way. What? How did them it? Reducer return empty obj for render. Dont look on obj in dispatch i will rework it.

**REDUCER**

```
case 'EDIT_ITEM':
            console.log(action.name, action.age, action.id);
            return state.map((item, index) =>
                action.id === index
                    ? {
                        name: action.name,
                        age: action.age
                    }
                    : item
            );
```

**App.js**

```
function EditUsers() {
        const listItems = users.map(function (value, index) {
            return (
                <form>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <div className="input-group-prepend">
                            <span className="input-group-text">{value.name}, {value.age}</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="New name" id="newName" className="form-control"/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="New age" id="newAge" className="form-control" aria-describedby="button-addon2"/>
                        <div className="input-group-append">
                            <button onClick={() => dispatch({
                                type: 'EDIT_ITEM',
                                id: index,
                                name: document.getElementById('newName').value,
                                age: document.getElementById("newAge").value
                            })}
                                    className="btn btn-outline-primary"
                                    type="button"
                                    id="button-addon2">
                                Изменить
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            )
        });
        return (
            <div>{listItems}</div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document.getElementById` to get the input values. In react, you should use a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) to manage input values.

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep the inputs uncontrolled, make the button's type "submit" and move the logic to the form's `onSubmit` callback and use the submit event to access the form fields.

Comment: I don't know what it looks like with Hooks, how can I take value from inputs? `e.target.name.value` or `this.input.name.value`?

Comment: `e.target.value` is enough.
`e.target` points to the DOM element where the event occurred, so `e.target.value` is the value in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to access the input values from the button's `onClick` event, but if you decide to leave the inputs uncontrolled and move the logic to the associated form's `onSubmit` callback, then you can access the form's field values from the `onSubmit` event.

Define a `submitHandler` function to consume both the `index` and submit event, `e`:

```
const submitHandler = index => e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent the default form action, important!
  const { newName, newAge } = e.target; // <-- destructure the inputs from the event target

  dispatch({
    type: "EDIT_ITEM",
    id: index,
    name: newName.value, // <-- extract the input value
    age: newAge.value // <-- extract the input value
  });
};
```

Here the path to the input value is `e.target.<fieldId>.value`. Notice I've also defined `submitHandler` to curry the index, which allows for more optimal usage when mapping elements.

Next, attach the `submitHandler` callback to the `onSubmit` prop of the form.

```
const listItems = users.map(function(value, index) {
  return (
    <form key={index} onSubmit={submitHandler(index)}>
      ...
```

Here the curried function `submitHandler(index)` takes the index and encloses it in an instance of the callback, returning a function that takes the `onSubmit` event object, `e => {...`.

Finally, update the button to have `type="submit"` and no `onClick` handler.

```
<button
  className="btn btn-outline-primary"
  type="submit"
  id="button-addon2"
>
  Изменить
</button>
```

Full code

```
const submitHandler = index => e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { newName, newAge } = e.target;

  dispatch({
    type: "EDIT_ITEM",
    id: index,
    name: newName.value,
    age: newAge.value
  });
};

function EditUsers() {
  const listItems = users.map(function(value, index) {
    return (
      <form key={index} onSubmit={submitHandler(index)}>
        <div className="input-group">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <span className="input-group-text">
              {value.name}, {value.age}
            </span>
          </div>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="New name"
            id="newName"
            className="form-control"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="New age"
            id="newAge"
            className="form-control"
            aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          />
          <div className="input-group-append">
            <button
              className="btn btn-outline-primary"
              type="submit"
              id="button-addon2"
            >
              Изменить
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  });
  return <div>{listItems}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit Incontrolled Input Form Submit]

Comment: thx a lot you are amazing! I wanted to know may be exist another metod get `value` from `input`, for this i asked my question

Comment: please tell me for why you send `key={index}` to `<form/>`? This is mean what 
each element has an independent `<form/>`?

Comment: @d2207 Yes, since you are mapping users, the mapped array will need need unique react keys on each outer element. Each user gets their own form element.